# Adding to a set while iterating (C++)

Tags: c++11, iterator

If I have the following code (assume the set is unordered set):

```
mySet.insert(0);
int i = 1;
for(auto itr = mySet.begin(); itr != mySet.end(); ++itr){
    mySet.insert(i);
    i++;
}
```

It would end up updating the set as it iterates and result in an endless loop. If I wanted instead to iterate over only the elements in the set before modifying, how could I ensure that the addition of new elements does not affect the iteartion?

If I were to do this with a list, the code would look like :

```
myList.push_front(0);
int i = 1;
for(auto itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); ++itr){
    myList.push_front(i);
    i++;
}
```

But there is not push_front method for sets (makes sense), but I wanted to do this while taking advantage of the fact that sets only contain unique elements.

Comment: Add it to some container and merge afterwards.

Comment: I mean yeah but I was kind of hoping to avoid things like that. If not I guess i'll just have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Possible workarounds:

1. Create a copy of the set, iterate over the copy.
2. Create a temporary set that you add new values to, then after the iteration add all values from the temporary set to your original set.

Comment: How do I create a deep copy of a set and then later destory it?

Comment: Why would you need a deep copy? A shallow copy is perfect for your scenario. As for destroying it, just let it go out of scope.

Comment: Either way, if you have a new question, it's best to post it as new question, not as comment. But search first, as there are plenty questions on SO about deep and shallow copies in C++. The answer you are looking for might already be here :)